# removeEventListener not working in restricting dragEvents to a particular class

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a list with multiple subsets and I wish to keep the dragEvents separate for each set, but I want to keep the list as one list:

```
<ul class="draggable-list">
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >ONE</li>      
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >TWO</li>
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >THREE</li>
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >one</li>
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >two</li>
   <li draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >three</li>
</ul>
```

I am adding dragover eventListeners to some elements only after dragstart commences, and then trying to remove them within the dropevent, but it isn't working. Both functions are scoped like this:

```
function addListenersToDraggable( li, ruleRep ){
   li.addEventListener( 'dragstart', dragStart )
   li.addEventListener( 'dragenter', dragEvt   )
   li.addEventListener( 'dragleave', dragEvt   )
   li.addEventListener( 'drop', dragEvt )

   function dragStart() {
      ...
      set.forEach( ruleLI => ruleLI.addEventListener( 'dragover' , dragOver ))
   }

   function dragOver(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   }

   function dragEvt(e){
      ...
      // if e.type == "drop"...
      set.forEach( ruleLI => ruleLI.removeEventListener( 'dragover' , dragOver ))
   }
}
```

I checked the set is grabbing correctly the elements and both sets match. I can drag and drop, but I can't remove the listeners. The only place I add `dragover` is within `dragstart`.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use `removeEventListener` **in the `dragStart`** function, just *before* adding the new listeners (not least of all because not all dragstarts finish with a successful drop).

Instead of attaching the event listener as a method of the element:
`li.addEventListener(...)` 
it is easier to keep track of the event listener if it is attached to the element as an object property (assuming you don't need multiple event listeners of the same type on the same element). This also ensures there is only one active event listener per element (if that is what you want)

```js
const draggables = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( ".draggable" ))
draggables.forEach( li => {
  li.addEventListener( 'dragstart', dragStart );
//***instead of eventListener methods on all elements:***
  // li.addEventListener( 'drop'     , dragEvt   );
  // li.addEventListener( 'dragenter', dragEvt   );
  // li.addEventListener( 'dragleave', dragEvt   );
 })

  function dragStart() {
    const dragEl   = this
    const parent   = dragEl.parentElement
    const siblings = Array.from( parent.children )
    dragStartIndex = siblings.indexOf( dragEl )
    const setName  = Array.from( dragEl.classList )
                          .find( className => className.startsWith( "set-" ))
    const set      = Array.from( parent.querySelectorAll( "." + setName ))

//*** removing the attached listeners is easy: ***
    siblings.forEach( li => {
      li.ondragover  = null 
      li.ondragenter = null
      li.ondragleave = null
      li.ondrop      = null
    })
//*** attach listeners only to elements in same class: ***
    set.forEach( li => {
      li.ondragover  = (e) => dragOver( e )
      li.ondragenter = (e) => dragEvt ( e )
      li.ondragleave = (e) => dragEvt ( e )
      li.ondrop      = (e) => dragEvt ( e )
    })
  }

  function dragOver( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function dragEvt( e ) {
    const parentList      = e.target.closest( '.draggable-list' )
    const thisLI          = e.target.closest( '.draggable-list>li' )
    const eventType       = e.type
    const dragEndIndex    = Array.from( parentList.children ).indexOf( thisLI )
    const dragEnterIndex  = Array.from( parentList.children ).indexOf( thisLI )
    if ( dragEnterIndex != -1 ){
      if ( dragEnterIndex > dragStartIndex ){
        if ( eventType == "dragenter"){
          thisLI.classList.add( 'darken-bottom' );
        } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
          thisLI.classList.remove( 'darken-bottom' );
        }
      } else if ( dragEnterIndex < dragStartIndex ){
        if ( eventType == "dragenter"){
          thisLI.classList.add( 'darken-top' );
        } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
          thisLI.classList.remove( 'darken-top' );
        }
      } else if ( dragEnterIndex == dragStartIndex ){
        if ( eventType == "dragenter"){
          thisLI.classList.add( 'darken' )
        } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
          thisLI.classList.remove( 'darken' )
        }
      }
      if ( eventType == "drop" ){
        moveDraggable( dragStartIndex, dragEndIndex, parentList )
      }
    }
  }
      
  function moveDraggable( fromIndex, toIndex, ul ) {
    const liToMove = ul.removeChild( ul.children[ fromIndex ] )
    ul.insertBefore( liToMove, ul.children[ toIndex ])
    if ( fromIndex != toIndex ){
      ul.children[ toIndex ].classList.add( "darken-plonk" )
      setTimeout( () => {
        ul.children[ toIndex ].classList.remove( "darken-plonk" )
      }, 300 )
    }
  }
```

```css
.set-1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.set-2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.set-1, .set-2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5rem;  
  list-style: none;
  width: 10rem;
}

.darken-bottom {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #be2edd;
}
.darken-top {
  border-top: 3px solid #be2edd;
}
.darken, .darken-bottom, .darken-top {
filter: brightness(90%);
transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}
.darken-plonk {
  filter: brightness(80%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="draggable-list">
   <li id="li1-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >ONE</li>      
   <li id="li2-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >TWO</li>
   <li id="li3-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1" >THREE</li>
   <li id="li4-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >one</li>
   <li id="li5-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >two</li>
   <li id="li6-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2" >three</li>
</ul>
```