# Drag and drop: Drop only if correct match

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have this drag and drop and it runs perfect. But I have different items to drop only in their corresponding dropzones. How can I achieve this?

```
function ablegenErlauben(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function ablegen(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    var target = ev.target;
    while (" "+target.className+" ".indexOf(" dropzone ") == -1) target = target.parentNode;
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

window.addEventListener("load",function () {
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".zielzone");
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        var zielzone = elms[i];
        zielzone.addEventListener("drop",ablegen);
        zielzone.addEventListener("dragover",ablegenErlauben);
    };

    elms = document.querySelectorAll("[draggable=true]")
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        var draggable = elms[i];
        draggable.addEventListener("dragstart",ziehen);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle this, but overall will come down to defining the permission function. In your permission logic, you can match dragged element id with dropped element id, and execute the logic.

In my example I made a 2nd param which accept an array. In this array you can define the container id if it's on drag element, and drag element id if it's on container. Then in my permission function I'll just check with array.includes(id), if it's return true then it's allowed to be dropped. Careful with some gotchas of Drag and Drop API such dropping into child element of onDrop.

```js
// data will take array of container id
function touchstart(e, data) {
  // store dragged element id as item
  e.dataTransfer.setData("item", e.target.id);
  // store array as string, if not provided, it store as null
  if (data != undefined) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("data", JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("data", JSON.stringify(null));
  }
}

// access will be defined from container, which array of allowed element id
function drop(e, access) {
  let item = e.dataTransfer.getData("item")
  let data = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("data"))
  let dropzone = e.target.id

  // define permission
  let permission = this.getAccess(item, dropzone, data, access)
  // prevent drop into child
  let str = dropzone.split('-')
  if (str[0] == 'el') {
    permission = false
  }
  if (permission) {
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(item))
  }
}


function getAccess(item, dropzone, data, access) {
  let permission = false
  // only run if data is provided, which != null
  if (data != null) {
    /* permission = data.includes(dropzone) */
    permission = data.includes(dropzone)
  }
  // if permission already granted, just exit
  if (permission) return permission
  //if permission still false, run from container access point
  if (access != null) {
    /*  permission = access.includes(item) */
    permission = access.includes(item)

  }
  return permission
}

function dragover(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0b79d0;
  background: #1F2227;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.el {
  color: white;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #42B883;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" ondrop="drop(event,['el-3'])" id="1" ondragover="dragover(event)">
  <div class=indicator>
    container 1
  </div>
  <div id="el-1" class="el" ondragstart="touchstart(event,['1','3'])" draggable="true" ondrop="return false">
    1 and 3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="2" ondrop="drop(event,['el-3'])" ondragover="dragover(event)">
  <div class=indicator>
    container 2
  </div>
  <div id="el-2" class="el" ondragstart="touchstart(event,['2','3'])" draggable="true" ondrop="return false">
    2 and 3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" id="3" ondragover="dragover(event)">
  <div class=indicator>
    container 3
  </div>
  <div id="el-3" class="el" ondragstart="touchstart(event,['3'])" draggable="true" ondrop="return false">
    1,2 and 3
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Alternative

To complement my answer above, here another alternative to probably achieve your goal, taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71150581/removeeventlistener-not-working-in-restricting-dragevents-to-a-particular-class) it uses class to limit event listener

```js
const draggables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".draggable"))
draggables.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  //***instead of eventListener methods on all elements:***
  // li.addEventListener( 'drop'     , dragEvt   );
  // li.addEventListener( 'dragenter', dragEvt   );
  // li.addEventListener( 'dragleave', dragEvt   );
})

function dragStart() {
  const dragEl = this
  const parent = dragEl.parentElement
  const siblings = Array.from(parent.children)
  dragStartIndex = siblings.indexOf(dragEl)
  const setName = Array.from(dragEl.classList)
    .find(className => className.startsWith("set-"))
  const set = Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll("." + setName))

  //*** removing the attached listeners is easy: ***
  siblings.forEach(li => {
    li.ondragover = null
    li.ondragenter = null
    li.ondragleave = null
    li.ondrop = null
  })
  //*** attach listeners only to elements in same class: ***
  set.forEach(li => {
    li.ondragover = (e) => dragOver(e)
    li.ondragenter = (e) => dragEvt(e)
    li.ondragleave = (e) => dragEvt(e)
    li.ondrop = (e) => dragEvt(e)
  })
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEvt(e) {
  const parentList = e.target.closest('.draggable-list')
  const thisLI = e.target.closest('.draggable-list>li')
  const eventType = e.type
  const dragEndIndex = Array.from(parentList.children).indexOf(thisLI)
  const dragEnterIndex = Array.from(parentList.children).indexOf(thisLI)
  if (dragEnterIndex != -1) {
    if (dragEnterIndex > dragStartIndex) {
      if (eventType == "dragenter") {
        thisLI.classList.add('darken-bottom');
      } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
        thisLI.classList.remove('darken-bottom');
      }
    } else if (dragEnterIndex < dragStartIndex) {
      if (eventType == "dragenter") {
        thisLI.classList.add('darken-top');
      } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
        thisLI.classList.remove('darken-top');
      }
    } else if (dragEnterIndex == dragStartIndex) {
      if (eventType == "dragenter") {
        thisLI.classList.add('darken')
      } else { // if eventType is leave or drop:
        thisLI.classList.remove('darken')
      }
    }
    if (eventType == "drop") {
      moveDraggable(dragStartIndex, dragEndIndex, parentList)
    }
  }
}

function moveDraggable(fromIndex, toIndex, ul) {
  const liToMove = ul.removeChild(ul.children[fromIndex])
  ul.insertBefore(liToMove, ul.children[toIndex])
  if (fromIndex != toIndex) {
    ul.children[toIndex].classList.add("darken-plonk")
    setTimeout(() => {
      ul.children[toIndex].classList.remove("darken-plonk")
    }, 300)
  }
}
```

```css
.set-1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.set-2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.set-1,
.set-2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style: none;
  width: 10rem;
}

.darken-bottom {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #be2edd;
}

.darken-top {
  border-top: 3px solid #be2edd;
}

.darken,
.darken-bottom,
.darken-top {
  filter: brightness(90%);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

.darken-plonk {
  filter: brightness(80%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="draggable-list">
  <li id="li1-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1">ONE</li>
  <li id="li2-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1">TWO</li>
  <li id="li3-1" draggable="true" class="draggable set-1">THREE</li>
  <li id="li4-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2">one</li>
  <li id="li5-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2">two</li>
  <li id="li6-2" draggable="true" class="draggable set-2">three</li>
</ul>
```